# BackboneJS + Codeigniter RESTful API - Strange issue when NOT setting LIMIT

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

I'm using the Codeigniter RESTful API to pass data to my Backbone App.

My SQL-statement for the API looks like this:

```
public function a_artists_get()  
{ 
  $this->load->database();
  $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM `artists` WHERE formated_name LIKE 'A%' LIMIT 0, 50";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  $data = $query->result();

  if($data) {
      $this->response($data, 200);
  } else {
      $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with letter a!'), 404);
  }
}
```

This works fine so far BUT when I remove the `LIMIT`-part of the query, the result of the query does not get displayed in my frontend, even though I can see in my console that the data is available as JSON. Once again, this only happens when I remove the `LIMIT`-part.

Another strange thing is, that if I set `LIMIT 0,100` - it works, but if I set `LIMIT 0,1000` - it doesnt work??! - Does Backbone have some kind of limit of what amount of data can be handled?

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Yes I did! It turned out to be an encoding issue. Setting it to `UTF-8 without BOM` solved it...